# How to embed pgfplots picture in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, inline-image

I want to include tikz/pgfplots pictures in an org-mode document both for inline visualisation and export.

I have tried approaches given in [this emacs-orgmode thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-07/msg00510.html) and in the [worg documentation dedicated to latex](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html). However, none provided me with a working example.

Based on the sources above I've tried the following:

```
#+begin_src latex :results output file graphics :file test.svg 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=Title, xlabel={X}, ylabel={Y}, legend entries={A,V}]
      \addplot [mark=square, thin, blue] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {my_csv1.csv};
      \addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {my_csv2.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

This produces a svg picture with missing features. In comparison, the pdf produced with the same code leads to the expected figure.

[image: Obtained figure with missing features]

I understood the process to generate a svg figure with a babel latex source code is different from the one to generate a pdf, hence the disparity. Actually, it seems that `htlatex` (called under the hood by `org-babel-execute:latex`) fails to produce the expected svg from the tex code.

How can I generate tikz/pgfplots pictures so they appear first inline in the org-mode document and then export them easily as I export the document to latex?

I'm using spacemacs with emacs 26.3